# decimals not being read properly in R

Tags: r, decimal, tibble

I am trying to get the whole number 193525.0768 but it gets its decimals removed (?). Please explain it to me.

```
df <- tibble(
  x = "193525.0768"
) %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x))

print(df, digits = 10) # decimals removed. I expect it to maintain the decimals numbers

# A tibble: 1 x 1
        x
    <dbl>
1 193525.

df[1,1][[1]] # decimals removed

# 193525

x <- "193525.0768"
print(as.numeric(x), digits = 10) # decimals not removed
# 193525.0768
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a printing issue, not a reading-in issue. The tibble print method doesn't take a digits argument - see `?print.tbl` for details. You can use `print.data.frame` explicitly to bypass the tibble print method and use the data.frame print method instead, which does take a `digits` argument:

```
tibble(x = "193525.0768") %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) %>% 
  print.data.frame(digits = 10)
#             x
# 1 193525.0768
```

Or you can change the default with the `pillar.sigfig` option (which is mentioned in `?print.tbl`). The default is 3 - which is confusing because if I were to take that literally I would expect 193525.0768 to print as 194000...  there's probably documentation in the `pillar` package explaining the reasoning.

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 10)

tibble(x = "193525.0768") %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x))
#             x
# 1 193525.0768
```

Alternately, use a data frame instead of a tibble:

```
data.frame(x = "193525.0768") %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) %>% 
  print(digits = 10)
#             x
# 1 193525.0768
```